# is there any way to initialize details in jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a problem with jquery datatable details initialization.
I need to get table with opened details after page has loaded.

I have a following code:

```
  function format(d) {
   return d;
   }
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/SHOP/Promotions/GenerateDetailsToJson",  //teraz w tym miejscu inicjuję dane do tabel
        success: function (result) {
            SetDetails(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Wystąpił nieoczekiwany błąd");
        }
    })

    dt = $('#table').DataTable(
        {   
            "aoColumnDefs": [
      { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0, 6, 7] }
            ]
        }
        );
      dt.on('draw', function () {
        $.each(detailRows, function (i, id) {
            $('#' + id + ' td:first-child').trigger('click');
        });
    });

    $('#table').DataTable();}

     var table_length = $('#table tbody tr').length; //HERE iS PROBLEM 

    var tr = document.getElementsByClassName("details");

    for (var i = 0; i < table_length; i++) {
        var row = dt.row(tr[i]);
        row.child(format(details[i])).show();
    }
      );
```

The problem is in last few lines in above code.
These lines need to initialize and open all jquery datatables details but these function do not execute at time and nothing is displayed.
I have have tried to use timeout it better worked but not like as wanted and for couple of refreshing one was with no data 
If You know any solution for that, please help.

Comment: Does your code even work? `$('#table').DataTable();}` what `}` doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must wait for ajax request to complete.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        //...
        success: function (result) {
            SetDetails(result);
            process();
        }
    });

    function process() {
        var table_length = $('#table tbody tr').length;

        var tr = document.getElementsByClassName("details");

        for (var i = 0; i < table_length; i++) {
            var row = dt.row(tr[i]);
            row.child(format(details[i])).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have made something similar after all table initialization and it worked

Answer (score 0):

1:    try removing the ajax call before the datatable code (maybe there is some error in ajax call which leads to non working of the code below it )

2:   in the ajax call , i beleive the url is wrong .

3:   is there a setdetails function present , if its not present , then the code will give error

4:  try run your code in firefox browser (with firebug on) , try googling about firebug if u do not know about it , but its recommended to use firebug (very helpful)

Comment: I have already found the problem's solution thanks you.
I only get ajax call on the end of document ready and executre previous problematic function on ajax success

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.when` and `.then` so that you can wait for your ajax to get complete and then execute the remaining initializations as below:

```
$.when(
$.ajax({
      ....
      ....
})).then(function()
{
    dt = $('#table').DataTable(
        .... 
        ....
    });
    //Other initializations.
});
```